# canvas not loading in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm learning canvas in html 5 and I want to manipulate an image in the canvas. However, I'm facing a roadblock in the first step itself. I am not able to display the image on the canvas.

Please look at this fiddle I created - http://jsfiddle.net/XsP76/

specifically, this is my javascript function.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("carice");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
});
```

The image is displayed in the fiddle, in firefox but not in chrome. What is going going wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I *think* I see the image in Chrome...

Comment: It's displaying here. Chrome ver 27.0.1453.94 m. It's ofcourse displaying in it's original size, cropped to the size of the canvas ofcourse, but it is displaying. Not sure what to say.

Comment: thanks a lot for that info. My chrome verion is 22.x. Due to lack of admin priviliges, I can't install a newer version of chrome.

Comment: Check the dev tools console, perhaps there is an error popping up there? Also try logging some of the vars you've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine here in Chrome / Canary.

I noticed you insert `<body>` tags in your fiddle; that makes double body tags as jsfiddle do this for you.

If you go to the source for that frame you will see:

```
...
</head>
<body>
  <body>
....
```

Try this update:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/XsP76/2/